is there any way to remove the gap between the numberBox and datagrid cell?
I know there are similar questions on this topic but this is different. I'm working on react to make a certain page which contain table. I try to create a dataGrid using devextreme code blocks which helps me to reduce the code time. The problem is while I try to take the input from the NumberBox I had noticed some gap between NumberBox and cell wall. How to remove it.
the code is:
<DataGrid
    dataSource={initialValues.tokenDetails.spPlans}
    showBorders={true}
>
    <Column
        dataField='shedName'
        caption={formatMessage('Shed')}
        allowEditing={false}
        alignment='center'
    />
    <Column
        dataField='stackName'
        caption={formatMessage('Stack')}
        allowEditing={false}
        alignment='center'
    />
    <Column
        dataField='moisture'
        caption={formatMessage('Moisture')}
        alignment='center'
        cellRender={(rowData) => (
            <div>
                <NumberBox
                    style={{ height: '25px', margin: 0, padding: 0 }}
                    defaultValue={rowData.data.moisture}
                    onValueChange={e => { validationforMoistureChange(e, rowData) }}
                />
                <div style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 12 }}>{rowData.data.errorMessage}</div>
            </div>
        )}
    />
</DataGrid>


I try to set padding and margin  to 0 (inline styling) but it not working
